# VSTS Nuget Publishing

Tags: nuget

I have a projects that I am preparing to push to the VSTS nuget server - private *within a build definition). I have one project that is pushing ok and shows up in the nuget explorer in Visual Studio. I have another project that depends on the first project as a dependency. I have configured the build process to interface with the dependent project on the private nuget server - and it builds ok. The packing fails though indicating that the nuget package from the orignal project cannot b found. The following is the scenario I am running in to:

project A Build
Project A pack nuget package
Project A publish nuget package

project B NUGET GET - Project A (passes)
project B Build (passes)
project B pack nuget package (fails)
   following error is reported

The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and 
  error(Unable to find 'A.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.)

Unsure why the packing of project B is looking for the project A package. The package B packing task is only pointing to the project B proj file - unclear why it is looking for the project A package that is not being packed into the current package

Answer (score 0):

OK - after researching I found what the problem was. The VSTS nuget TASK for the put operation works explicitly on a Visual Studio .net project (not a solution). After realizing that the NUGET packing operation needs to know the location of other included nuget packages I understood what was happening. Since the identified location is the Visual Studio project it is looking for the package location in the folder above location of the target visual Studio project. Now my system does not maintain the solutions in this fashion - so locating the Package folder was failing. What would have been nice is if the error message had indicated that it could not find the package in the location being looked at. Once I understood what was happening I found that there is a config file called nuget.config that is placed in the same location the target Visual Studio project is in that can specify the location of the nuget packages.

```
 <configuration>
  <config>
   <add key="repositoryPath" 
    value="..\..\..\OrderIT\Solutions\DataManagementCore\packages" />
   </config>
 </configuration>
```

This solved the problem. It would be nice if MS had prepped the NUGET task to take a Visual Studio solution and then ability to select the project from the solution that is being packed so the package folder could be located (by default Visual Studio will place the package folder in the location the nuget operation is looking).

Peter